# Installing HTTP module in Python 3.8.8

Tags: python, http, module, python-3.8, python-egg-cache

Not able to install HTTP module in Python 3.8.8.

[image: Screenshot of the Error]

> WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/f0/787d609561ada283d6755e6f1198aa65a6eea075297725344e8f8c12eb03/http-0.1.tar.gz#sha256=0e66b52fc46640edd547c3c47a7913e0c5f76a69db6fb09e7b48c5f7866b2c37 (from https://pypi.org/simple/http/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: `http` was written for Python 2. Indeed, `pip install http` works with Python 2.7.

Comment: Try importing it directly with `import http`, without `pip install http` as it comes with Python 3.8.8. I'm not sure what it does exactly, but the http module is pre-installed for the Python version you're using; I think installing it with `pip install http` just messes it up. I tried installing it and got the same error, but I can simply import it, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html) is built-in, you don't have to install it.

Use `import http` to import it in python code.